# How to determine the nature of this equilibrium point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If we find the equilibrium point and linearize the system

$x'=-x+ay+x^2y\\
y'=b-ay-x^2y,$

we get that the point is $(b, \frac{b}{a+b^2})$ and the matrix associated with the linearilized system is

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-a+b^2}{a+b^2} & a+b^2\\ 
-\frac{2b^2}{a+b^2} & -(a+b^2)
\end{bmatrix}

To determine the nature of the equilibrium point we need to find the eigenvalues of this matrix. Finding the eigenvalues, we get this:

$\lambda = -\frac{\pm\sqrt{(a+b^2)^2[(a+b^2)^2+2(a-b^2)-4(a+b^2)]+(a-b^2)^2}+(a+b^2)^2+(a-b^2)}{2(a+b^2)}$.

From my understanding, since this is a biological model (Sel'kov model), a model for breaking down of sugar, $a$, $b >0$.

But I have no idea how to analyze $\lambda$ since I don't know what values $a$ and $b$ can take and how $a$ and $b$ are related. I'd appreciate some help please.

Comment: Well, I think they ask you to make full bifurcation diagram. All that you have to do is to analyze what kind of roots this characteristic equation might have.  Use Vieta's formulas: for example, $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = {\rm det}\, J$ and your Jacobi matrix $J$ has always positive determinant; hence, two possibilities for roots -- either they are real and have the same sign or they are complex. In both cases the sign ${\rm tr}\, J$ is the same as sum of eigenvalues and this determines the stability. The final part (determine, when eigenvalues are complex) is left to you :)

Comment: It appears that it was simpler than that - one just had to analyze the different cases by setting $\beta =$ the first squared term under the square root, $\alpha = $ what is outside the square root, etc.

Comment: What could be simpler than Vieta's theorem? :) Frankly speaking, both methods have the same 'complexity', but you seemed to be struggling with analysis of eigenvalues per se.

Comment: Don't know Vieta's theorem yet :)